# Intercept and assert private exception using junit

Tags: java, junit

There are multiple question similar to mine with a small difference I want to catch private inner exception (if that's accurate definition), and then assert it. I come up with test below. I'm looking for similar method to one is Spock `thrown()`. Thanks for your help in advance. I do not have much experience with junit, if that's trivial for you just answer or link page that might help me understand.

Thanks for your help and support! :D

The Exception `reactor.core.Exceptions$RetryExhaustedException`

```
public abstract class Exceptions {

    static final class RetryExhaustedException extends IllegalStateException {

        RetryExhaustedException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }

        RetryExhaustedException(String message, Throwable cause) {
            super(message, cause);
        }
    }
}
```

My test

```
    @Test
    void exampleTest() {
        // given:
        stubToForce5xxResponse();

        // when:
        var ex = getExceptionThrown(() -> exampleService.exampleMethod());

        // then:
        Assertions.assertThat(ex).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(ex.getClass().getName()).isEqualTo("reactor.core.Exceptions$RetryExhaustedException");
        Assertions.assertThat(ex.getMessage()).isEqualTo("Retries exhausted: 3/3");
    }

    private Throwable getExceptionThrown(Runnable runnable) {
        try {
            runnable.run();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`assertThrows`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable))? Given your example, you can use it like `var ex = assertThrows(RetryExhaustedException.class, () -> exampleService.exampleMethod());`.

Comment: It's good answer but I can't access RetryExhaustedException (private). The only way is to access it with reflection and I do not know how (if possible).

Comment: OK, I see. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76468109/3429133).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example code, I assume you use AssertJ:

```java
@Test
void exampleTest() {
    stubToForce5xxResponse();

    assertThatThrownBy(() -> exampleService.exampleMethod())
        .isInstanceOfSatisfying(IllegalStateException.class, ex -> {
            assertThat(ex.getClass().getName()).isEqualTo("reactor.core.Exceptions$RetryExhaustedException");
            assertThat(ex).hasMessage("Retries exhausted: 3/3");
        });
}
```

If you want to stick to JUnit Jupiter assertions:

```java
@Test
void exampleTest() {
    stubToForce5xxResponse();

    var ex = assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class, () -> exampleService.exampleMethod());

    assertEquals("reactor.core.Exceptions$RetryExhaustedException", ex.getClass().getName());
    assertEquals("Retries exhausted: 3/3", ex.getMessage());
}
```

(Note that AssertJ is `asserThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected)`, whereas JUnit Jupiter is `assertEquals(expected, actual)`.)

Comment: It works. Thanks. It feels bad I didn't think of super type